# Request timed out Error while hitting the api

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

While Hitting the api i am getting this Exception **A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.**
Some times it's gave proper result but some times it produce this Exception.

Code Block

```
try
            {
                string id = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss");

                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 35000);
                httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(serverAddress);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", uri);
                
                var responseMessage = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

                var responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    throw new RestException
                    {
                        ResponseCode = (int)responseMessage.StatusCode,
                        ResponseContent = responseContent
                    };
                }

                return responseContent;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception($"The GET request timed out. {ex.Message}");
            }
```

Comment: Did you manage to tell where does the code crash? and the exception thrown is created in the    if(!responseMessage.IssuccessStatusCode)    or in the catch?

Comment: In the catch its throwing exception.